# angularJS watching values of an object list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I have a List containing objects in my angular js project. Each object of the list contains a name and a value. This value is bound to a text field. The list is displayed on a grid and when ever the grid row is selected, the form with the bound value gets displayed.

I have added the following code to watch the list for possible changes to its object values.

```
 $scope.$watch('myList', function(newval, oldval){

 },true);
```

The HTML is

```
<div ng-repeat="myObject in myList">
    <input id="myObject.objectName-{{$index}}" ng-model="myObject.objectValue"/>
</div>
```

The problem is the watch gets executed whenever the row is selected not only when the values gets changed.

any improvement or suggestions pls?

Comment: It may help to see a fiddle/plunkr

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Do you know about deep watching? (3rd argument of $watch method)

Comment: try putting a true as the last param:  `$scope.$watch('myList', function() { }, true); ` which might be what you are looking for (@NicolasMoise I just saw you posted first).

Comment: I already had the deep watch. What I need is a much detailed watch statement as I understand.

Comment: simply saying ,, my list is bound to an ng-grid as well. When ever I click a row in the grid or change values of the list bound data filed, the watch gets executed. I need this to happen only when the input values change..

Comment: show the output of `console.log(newval)`

Comment: It looks like you're setting a local scope value `myList` whenever a row is selected. If that's the case, you're always going to trigger the watch on `myList`, since it's new each time.